# Cannot access geth by JSON-RPC. It returns {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I've tried to access geth by rpc.

```
$ geth --dev --datadir mydir --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" console
```

However it has returned the error. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}
```

**Update**
I've got connected by rpc, however on the browser-solidity I cannot connect my private node.

[image]

Comment: What is the JSON-RPC request you executed?

Comment: `http://localhost:8545`

Comment: Is the answer correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it is the command you are using.

This works:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"currentBlock":"0x1eb260","highestBlock":"0x1eb478","knownStates":"0x0","pulledStates":"0x0","startingBlock":"0x1eaea3"}}
```

And this does not work:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 50
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}
```

Here are some simple commands you can test with:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_coinbase","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}

user@Kumquat:~$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_gasPrice","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x4a817c800"}
```

Comment: `$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545`

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":false}`

Comment: Yup. Your command is working perfectly. Your private node is not syncing and so the result is false.

Comment: It seems doesn't work. I'll try debugging it.

Comment: > rpc
{
  modules: {
    admin: "1.0",
    debug: "1.0",
    eth: "1.0",
    miner: "1.0",
    net: "1.0",
    personal: "1.0",
    rpc: "1.0",
    shh: "1.0",
    txpool: "1.0",
    web3: "1.0"
  },
  getModules: function(callback)
}
My node uses rpc:1.0. Is it the reason?

Comment: Your return result `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":false}` is the correct result. The following will work on the Mainnet blockchain, returning the balance at address `0x0000...0000` - `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "latest"],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x16d53d844d5d4397305"}`

RPC module v1.0 is perfect.

Comment: $ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_coinbase","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x86d13ef4629e9b855a8045cd8b2f67ba6a736ba6"}

Comment: I've got data from node. Thx! However, at the browser-solidity, I cannot connect the local private node. Could you figure out what is the reason?

Comment: Please ask a new questions and I'll look into it.

Comment: I've questioned! Plz check it:)
http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/invalid-json-rpc-response