# Windows curl error with JSON-RPC

Tags: json-rpc, windows

Using Windows, when I started Geth with:

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr 192.168.1.9 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal" --datadir C:\Users\BulldogBud\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata --networkid 3 console
```

Receiving:

> I1206 11:55:12.857903 node/node.go:410] HTTP endpoint opened: http://192.168.1.9:8545

I opened another Console typing:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":1}' http://192.168.1.9:8545
```

Receiving :

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of value"}}

How can I fix this issue? Thank you in advance!

EDIT
after several attempts, giving:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_coinbase","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
```

the new error message is:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8545: Connection refused

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7794/cannot-access-geth-by-json-rpc-it-returns-jsonrpc2-0-errorcode-326/7795#7795

Comment: Unfortuately I restarted Geth:

    > admin.startRPC()
I1206 14:18:47.079120 node/node.go:410] HTTP endpoint opened: http://localhost:8545
true
Experiencing again:

    C:\>curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"}}

Comment: I just tried your second RPC string from above, but I changed http://192.168.1.9 to http://localhost. Got a perfect result. I start geth with 

```geth --rpc --rpcapi"eth,net,web3,personal"```

The --rpcport defaults anyway. Don't know about the rest of the params you use to start geth

Comment: I don't know how to proceed to solve it....I'm using Windows 10, is there any particular version of Curl to download?

Comment: Have you found a way to resolve this issue? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geth response: invalid content type, only application/json is supported](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30651/geth-response-invalid-content-type-only-application-json-is-supported)

Comment: On Windows you need to escape all the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Let use [POST MAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

With:

- Method: Post
- URL: http://localhost:8545
- Header: Content-Type: application/json
- Body: raw

> ```
> {
>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>   "method": "eth_coinbase",
>   "params": ["0x68656c6c6f20776f726c64"],
>   "id": 1
> }
> ```

worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try to set

```
--rpccorsdomain="http://yourip/"
```

Or

```
--rpccorsdomain="*"
```

Tell me if that work!

Also sometime I use NGROK this way I can create a domain, point to 8545 port and use that domain instead that IP