# Geth response: invalid content type, only application/json is supported

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I started `geth` on a remote server running on rinkeby with the parameters `--rinkeby --fast --cache=128 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0`

When I try to test my access to `geth` using

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' http://my-geth-remote-server:8545
```

I received the response

```
invalid content type, only application/json is supported
```

Pretty confused about the error, isnt the RPC payload given in JSON already?

Geth used is `Geth/v1.7.3-unstable-9b97f983/linux-amd64/go1.9.2`

**Response of curl after adding -v**

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":42}' http://8.8.8.8:8545 -v`

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://8.8.8.8:8545/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 8.8.8.8...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) port 8545 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 8.8.8.8:8545
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 57
>
* upload completely sent off: 57 out of 57 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Mon, 13 Nov 2017 21:39:48 GMT
< Content-Length: 109
<
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"}}
* Connection #0 to host 8.8.8.8 left intact
```

**curl --version**

```
curl 7.55.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.55.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.23.1
Release-Date: 2017-08-09
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy Metalink
```

This is the windows versions of `curl`.

Comment: add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: may be helpful to also show us what your curl version is. `curl --version`

Comment: @LibertyLocked Updated question with details... its a windows version of `curl`, my macbook is currently down

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `curl.exe` on Windows and is having issues with quotes. See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514199/how-to-send-double-quote-in-d-parameter-for-curl-exe)

Comment: @LibertyLocked Yes! This command works now `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"web3_clientVersion\",\"params\":[],\"id\":42}" http://8.8.8.8:8545`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [Geth JSON RPC docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC)

> The curl options below might return a response where the node
>   complains about the content type, this is because the --data option
>   sets the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded . If your
>   node does complain, manually set the header by placing -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" at the start of the call.

You should add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` if you get a content type complaint.

So your request should be

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":42}' http://myserver.com:8545
```

If you use `curl.exe` on Windows you have to escape all the double quotes

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"web3_clientVersion\",\"pa‌​rams\":[],\"id\":42}‌​" http://myserver.com:8545
```

Comment: Got the error `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid character '\\'' looking for beginning of value"}}`

Comment: You may have other network issues. Try adding a `-v` and see what comes up

Comment: I added to the original post the response I get after adding a `-v`...

Answer (score 0):

Try `http://localhost:8545` instead of `my-geth-remote-server`. This is assuming you haven't edited your `~/.bash_profile`. Hope this helps!

> UPDATE: Here's a screenshot of me running the same command locally.
>   Perhaps there's a problem with the remote instance.
>   [image]
>   Double check that the JSON you're sending is valid https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to curl the remote geth server instead of geth on my localhost...

Comment: ahh I see, I assumed it was a local development environment.

Answer (score 0):

For my issue using curl on Windows 10 with the environment variable already setup,

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"eth_blockNumber\",\"params\":[],\"id\":83}" https://some-node-url.com
```

I needed to replace all single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`

even though the example I was using had a single quote.

And also add `\` in front of all the double quotes inside the param brackets `{}`